# Variable field names in $.get in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get my .get call to send the name of the input field used (In this case a select) as the GET parameter key, and the value of the select as the value of the corresponding GET parameter. However, I can't seem to get variable GET keys to work, as jQuery whines about "missing : after property id".

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
$('.feedback_select').change(function() {
    $.get(
        '/feedback',
        {
           $(this).attr('name') : $(this).val()
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: BTW, that's a _Javascript_ syntax error, not a jQuery error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
```

Then pass `data` to `$.get()`.

PS: You can simply do `this.name` to avoid creating two jQuery objects. Or you could do `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this` instead of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the object by hand:

```
var params = {};
params[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
```